# Query graph to enum news pages

Tags: microsoft-graph

I'm trying to enumerate pages of a communication site through Graph call.

However, I don't see the page library in the results of this query :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/
```

Is it possible, or should I fall back to REST query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, though it's currently a beta feature. Docs are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-list?view=graph-rest-beta). An example is:

```
graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/pages
```